# Existe alguma forma de calcular um padrão do espaço extra de uma fonte?

Tags: css, font, css-font-size

Estou tentando montar um layout o mais "pixel perfect" possível, porém sempre me deparei com esse problema, utilizando fontes grandes, existe um espaço a mais a cima e a baixo da fonte, como se fosse um padding/margin. Procurei sobre o assunto, tentando relacionar com o line-height, porém sem sucesso. Alguém tem alguma explicação de como chegar o mais próximo do tamanho da fonte?

Pelo que vi o "jeito" é utilizar o line-height negativo e tentar ajustar, porém cada fonte teria um line-height negativo diferente. Também me sugeriram procurar mais sobre o "**vertical rhythm**", "**half-leading**", mas só me gerou mais dúvidas.

Segue um exemplo abaixo para ilustrar melhor o caso:

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-size:16px;
}
body{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
h1{
  outline:1px solid red;
  font-size:120px;
  vertical-align:text-top;
  line-height:normal;
}
h2{
  outline:1px solid blue;
  font-size:90px;
  margin-top:10px;
}
h4{
  font-size:16px;
  line-height:normal;
  outline:1px solid green;
  /*line height = 24px;*/
  /* 16 * 1.5 = 24px; */

}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<h1>Font h1</h1>
<h2>Font h2</h2>
<h3>Font h3</h3>
<div class="wrapper">
  <h4>Font h4</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Se você zerou `padding` e `margin`, creio que talvez a única, e provavelmente a melhor forma seria pelo `line-height` mesmo, em vez de usar `line-height:normal` utilize ele menor que a fonte, exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/leonardorodrigues/k6ebopvn/1/

Comment: @LeonardoRodrigues e existe algum padrão pra calcular esse line-height? Foi o único jeito que achei também, porém em algumas fontes que uma letra um pouco maior que a outra também não consigo alinhar com o line-height

Comment: talvez existe, se você utilizar um css framework(como o Sass ou Less). Mas pelo css básico creio que não

Answer (score 0):

Esse espaço é de fonte pra fonte, não parece ter um padrão correto, como já disseram nos comentários, a utilização do `line-height` é a melhor opção.
Já para calcular o valor, você pode usar a função `calc()`do próprio *CSS* ou mesmo valor por porcentagem, pois o `line-height` aceita esse tipo de valor.

E uma forma seria definir uma classe para cada tipo de fonte que você está utilizando junto a essas correções de tamanho.

**Ex:**

```
.roboto{
  font-family: Roboto;
  /* quanto maior a fonte, a linha segue de forma relativa */
  line-height: 90%;
}
```

ou

```
.roboto{
  font-family: Roboto;
  /* Sempre diminui 20 pixels fixo no tamanho da linha de acordo com o font-size atual */
  line-height: calc(100% - 20px;
}
```

Ambos não te garantem esse *"pixel perfect"* pois são valores relativos, mas é uma forma de contornar esse esquema dos espaços das fontes.